# Проблемки с математикой

Tags: математика

Решал тут тестовое задание на одном из ресурсов по изучению python. Выглядит оно так:
Улитка ползет по вертикальному шесту высотой h метров, поднимаясь за день на a метров, а за ночь спускаясь на b метров. На какой день улитка доползет до вершины шеста?

Программа получает на вход натуральные числа h, a, b.

Программа должна вывести одно натуральное число. Гарантируется, что a>b

Решение составителя задания такое:

```
h = int(input())
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
print((h - a - 1) // (a - b) + 2)
```

у меня же получилось решить циклом. Мое решение менее изящно и более громоздко.
Я до сих пор не понимаю откуда беруться цифры '-1'  и '+2' в решении разраба.
Может ли кто-нибудь мне объяснить что происходит и как вообще появилось это решение? Видимо я чего-то не понимаю в математике.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

За один день улитка проползает в сумме `a-b` метров. В последний день — проползя `a` метров, улитка достигает вершины. Т.е. если это `n`-й день, то `(n-1)*(a-b) + a >= h`, но `(n-2)*(a-b) + a < h`.

Дальше расписывать надо?

**Update**

Расписываем... Второе условие дает

```
h-a > (n-2)*(a-b)
```

или, поскольку все числа целые,

```
h-a-1 >= (n-2)*(a-b)
```

откуда, используя целочисленное же деление,

```
n = (h-a-1)//(a-b) + 2
```

Comment: Да, просьба расписать, если считаете, что разработчик прав в своей формуле. Так как при h=10, a = 5, b=4.9 по формуле выше улитка потратит 42 дня ((10-5-1))// (5-4.9) +2). А на самом деле?

Comment: @Сергей по условиям задачи все числа целые, так что ваш пример некорректен.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да, спасибо, пропустил. По факту свели к такому виду более классическую `1+ math.ceil((h-a)/(a-b))`

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо за ответ, но все равно ничего не понятно. 
Это (n-1)*(a-b) + a >= h если переводить на человеческий язык получается (количество дней без одного) * (путь за сутки) + путь за день. Увеличивая n на 1 рано или поздно узнаем сколько дней понадобится. А вот дальше непонятно ничего. Зачем и почему вы пишите "...но (n-2)*(a-b) + a < h" И главный вопрос почему НО? Дальше конечно же все тоже в тумане)

Comment: @Вова «Зачем и почему вы пишите ...» — это условие всего лишь означает что в предыдущий день улитка не доползла до вершины.